# How can I SSH targeting VPN tunnel

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, vpn, routing

I'm trying to make an SSH connection to my VPN server.

I'm connection the VPN with openConnect like this

```
echo PASS | sudo openconnect --juniper https://example/ -u user --passwd-on-stdin
```

This will by my `route -n` result

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp3s0
151.151.91.171  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
151.151.91.9    192.168.1.254   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp3s0
161.251.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp3s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp3s0
```

I can ssh to my target witch in my case is

```
ssh pi@151.151.91.91 -p 22
```

**IT WORKS!**

### **But,**

since I need to change the traffic to enp3s0 I'll use this command (I'm adding vpn-slice)

```
echo PASS | sudo openconnect --juniper https://example/ -u user --passwd-on-stdin -s 'vpn-slice 192.168.1.92'
```

**But now I cant ssh to my destination, It will just hang**

Also my route changed to this

```
 Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp3s0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp3s0
151.151.0.4     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
151.151.0.4     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    1      0        0 tun0
151.151.0.5     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
151.151.0.5     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    1      0        0 tun0
151.151.91.9    192.168.1.254   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp3s0
161.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp3s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp3s0
192.168.1.92    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
```

I tried to use `-b` option with ssh
e.g `ssh -b 151.151.91.179(local IP4) admin@151.151.91.91(destination) -p 22`
but had no result

### Question

**How can I choose my tun0 route when SSH'ing to my destination**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Without `vpn-slice`**, you write that your target host has an IP address of `151.151.91.91`.

But then when you invoke openconnect **with `vpn-slice`**, you *aren't routing traffic to that host* through the VPN:

```
echo PASS | sudo openconnect --juniper \
  https://example/ -u user --passwd-on-stdin -s 'vpn-slice 192.168.1.92'
```

As **you showed**, your routing table *does not contain* an entry to send traffic to the target (`151.151.91.91`) through the VPN… so when you try to connect to it with `ssh`, that traffic is going through your regular network adapter, and getting nowhere.

If you want `vpn-slice` to send traffic for this host through the VPN — and only this host — then you need to tell it so:

```
echo PASS | sudo openconnect --juniper \
  https://example/ -u user --passwd-on-stdin -s 'vpn-slice 151.151.91.91'
```

I suggest adding the `-v` and/or `--dump` flags to `vpn-slice` to get a better idea for how it works.  And please submit an issue or PR on Github if there's something specific that you think should be improved or clarified in the documentation.

*(I wrote [vpn-slice](https://github.com/dlenski/vpn-slice).)*